# Why os.system is reading only part of the command?

Tags: python, windows, shell, console

I have a Thumbnail_Handler class which has this method, which is supposed to run a file with Adobe Photoshop:

```
def abrir_photoshop(self):
        target = self.path_copia
        norm_path = os.path.normpath(r"C:\\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\\Photoshop.exe")
        cmd = '"' + norm_path + '" "' + target + '"'
        print(cmd)
        proc = os.system(cmd)
        for filename in os.listdir(PATH_THUMBNAIL + self.nome_playlist):
            if re.match(self.id_video_original + '.*.png', filename):
                self.set_status(status_thumb.PNG_EXPORTADO)
                return filename
```

The command that is printed on the `print(cmd)` line is this: `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\Photoshop.exe" "C:\\Users\\adassa\Desktop\\Thiago\\Youtube Almir\\\PSDs\Não Temas - 8PydQGvI0E4.psd"`

If I simply copy this, and paste to Powershell, or to the common Windows shell, it works as intended, but when python runs the command, I get: `'C:\Program' is not recognized as a command.` I reckon this means that the command is going without the double quotes. Why does this happen, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i tried a path similar to yours it only tried to run 'C:\Program' if the path did not existed, otherwise it worked fine, but since you said it worked when you manually copied the path maybe it's something else.

I found two ways to force the proper path:

### Solution 1: Quote only part of the path

```
norm_path = os.path.normpath(r'C:\"Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\Photoshop.exe"')
```

### Solution 2: Escape the space with a caret

```
norm_path = os.path.normpath(r'C:\Program^ Files\Adobe\Adobe^ Photoshop 2021\Photoshop.exe')
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried your first solution and it worked. I wonder why it works like that, though.

Comment: @ThiagoPereiraMaia: Are you sure the the 1st solution works with **one quoted argument**? Cause I tried and it doesn't. If you only run *Photoshop* that also works with "full quoting" as you tried. Anyway, this answer only provides (lame) workarounds, it's incomplete, and it doesn't answer the question, so it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`mslex.quote` from [mslex](https://pypi.org/project/mslex/) package looks like a solution to your case.

`shelx.quote` exits for same task on unix-like systems.

Comment: Have you tried *mslex*? I'm not sure it would work in this scenario (with *os.system*).

Answer (score 0):

*os.system* calls [[MS.Docs]: system, _wsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem), which in turn calls the command interpreter (***cmd***).

When *system* invokes *cmd* (I didn't see any official documentation to support this, so I'm posting a screenshot to support my statement), it **passes the */c* argument**:

[image: img0]

According to [[MS.Docs]: cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) or `cmd /?` (**emphasis** is mine):

> - **If you specify /c** or /k, cmd processes, the remainder of string, and the quotation marks are preserved only if **all of the following conditions are met**:
>
>   - You don't also use /s.
>   - **You use exactly one set of quotation marks**.
>   - You don't use any special characters within the quotation marks (for example: & < > ( ) @ ^ | ).
>   - You use one or more white-space characters within the quotation marks.
>   - The string within quotation marks is the name of an executable file.
>
> **If the previous conditions aren't met**, string is processed by examining the first character to verify whether it is an opening quotation mark. If the first character is an opening quotation mark, it is stripped along with the closing quotation mark. Any text following the closing quotation marks is preserved.

So, when passing a **quoted executable, followed by a quoted argument, *cmd* alters the command** yielding the weird results you're seeing.

I don't know if this behavior could be avoided, (maybe *symlink*s with no spaces in their path could be created and passed to *os.system*), but that would be just a lame workaround (*gainarie*). The common sense approach would be to use [[Python.Docs]: subprocess - Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import subprocess


def quote(s):
    return '"' + s + '"'


def os_system(*args):
    cmd = " ".join(args)
    print("\nRun command: [{:s}]".format(cmd))
    return os.system(cmd)


def main(*argv):
    exe = os.path.normpath(r"c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe")
    quoted_exe = quote(exe)
    files = [
        "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951\dummy_no_spaces.pdf",
        "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951\dummy with spaces.pdf",
    ]

    if len(argv):
        print("Using subprocess")
        for file in files:
            subprocess.call([exe, file])
        return 0

    os_system(quoted_exe)
    os_system(exe)
    for file in files:
        os_system(quoted_exe, file)
        os_system(quoted_exe, quote(file))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
> Run command: ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"]
>
> Run command: [c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe]
> 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Run command: ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951\dummy_no_spaces.pdf]
>
> Run command: ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951\dummy_no_spaces.pdf"]
> 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Run command: ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951\dummy with spaces.pdf]
>
> Run command: ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951\dummy with spaces.pdf"]
> 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951]> :: !!! Now running via subprocess !!!
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066659951]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py 1
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Using subprocess
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen:

- In the 1<sup>st</sup> run (*os.system*), the variants that worked were (quoted executable):

  - Without arguments
  - With unquoted arguments (but for the file with spaces in its path, *Acrobat Reader* wasn't able to open it, so it also failed - but at a later stage)
- In the 2<sup>nd</sup> one (*subprocess*), everything worked smoothly (and *Acrobat Reader* had no problem opening the files - you'll have to trust me on this one :) ), no additional quoting required at all